# The mechanism behind the Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, synchrotron-radiation, hall-effect

It has been known for 130 years that a moving electron entering an external magnetic field is deflected (Lorentz force, Hall effects, synchrotrons). What I have never read is a description of how this happens.

Comment: With questions like this, I think it is important to ask yourself beforehand what kind of explanation would satisfy you. There are deeper explanations of the Lorentz force, but they require a lot more background. However, judging from your post, you might end up asking a 'why' or 'how' question again. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MO0r930Sn_8&ab_channel=nebulajr is very relevant for this.

Comment: @KennethGoodenough What are the deeper explanations? Furthermore I have an new question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/648126/what-does-the-lorentz-force-have-to-do-with-the-exchange-of-photons