# What does the Lorentz force have to do with the exchange of photons?

Tags: photons, virtual-particles

For the Lorentz force a propagating photon and a magnetic field are involved, I cannot see a virtual photon exchange between charges. The Lorentz force has nothing to do with the exchange of photons between electrons.

What does the Lorentz force have to do with the exchange of photons?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question is related to my closing your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648104/50583) as a duplicate of questions asking about explanations of the Coulomb force.

Since electromagnetism follows from [combining the Coulomb force and special relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3618/50583), any explanation for the Coulomb force is also an explanation for the Lorentz force.